# Oracle Statement Missing Expression

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, expression

I'm having trouble figuring out the missing expression from the following statement. What am I missing? Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT c.first || ' ' || AS "Name", s.start_date AS "PROB Start Date", s.end_date AS "PROB End Date", pc.con_freq AS "Frequency" 

FROM criminals c, sentences s, prob_contact pc 

WHERE c.criminal_id = s.criminal_id

AND s.violations BETWEEN pc.low_amt AND pc.high_amt;
```

As far as the JOIN goes it would be like this: (**corrected statement**)

```
SELECT c.first || ' ' || c.last AS "Name", s.start_date AS "PROB Start Date", s.end_date AS "PROB End Date", pc.con_freq AS "Frequency"

FROM criminals c JOIN sentences s ON c.criminal_id = s.criminal_id

JOIN prob_contact pc ON s.violations BETWEEN pc.low_amt AND pc.high_amt;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the very first expression:

```
SELECT c.first || ' ' || AS "Name", . . .
-------------------------^
```

Presumably you mean:

```
SELECT c.first || ' ' || c.last AS "Name", . . .
```

Also, you should learn to use explicit `join` syntax (although that has nothing to do with your problem).